# Configuring tests skip in deep modules structure

Tags: maven

I have a structure of maven modules:

```
mavenProjectRoot/
  a/
    a1/
    a2/
  b/
    b1/
    b2/
```

And need to configure certain tests skipping in module a1 from root pom.xml.

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
           <exclude>a/a1/**/*java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

But it seems my exclude expression is not correct, how to do that?

PS. I have created [project sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6d6llKsfRooRUlFX3FrM1NJVTA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skips the tests in a1 when you do "mvn test" from the root, you should write your snippet in a1 pom.xml with this modification:

```
<exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
```

But I recommend you to make two profiles in the root, one which runs all the tests and another which runs all the tests except the a1 tests.

Comment: I have created project sample (check question page)

Comment: You should copy the plugin configuration in the parent pom (not in the a1 pom, so remove from there), and when you run all the tests from the parent, the tests from a1 are skipped

Comment: Just changed (sample updated), not working, please check am I done what you said.

Comment: See the modifications in the post

Comment: Changing pom.xml just a level above is working, but I have to find the way to configure modules from root pom.xml. Today I am configuring it from root pom.xml by excluding required packages and tests without modules specification, but in case where the same package defined in two test modules it would be excluded from both.